# oozie submits only 10 concurrent jobs (max)

Tags: oozie

Our workflow has over 150 jobs, but oozie ,at any given time, only submits max 10 concurrent jobs. We have enough TaskTrackers to handle all 150 jobs.

Any idea how we can increase max concurrent jobs submitted by oozie ?

Answer (score 0):

check these default settings, maybe there is one that helps
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/oozie-default.xml